# In C++ , are statements in try block executed that are present after the throw statement (in case Exception is raised)?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

Please tell me if anything after the throw statement is executed or not.

For example , in the code below , why do my IDE raises error for '10//0' if it is not going to be executed ?

```
void check_exception()

{

    char a = 'A';
    char b = 'B';
    try
    {
        if (a == 'A')
            throw "Hello";
        
        cout << "\nLet's check if this line is printed or not";
        cout << "\nB is : " << b << " A has been thrown : " << 10/0;
        
    }
    catch (const char* check)
    {
        cout << "\n\nReceived exception " << check;
    }
}
```

Comment: You get a warning for `10 / 0` because the compiler or perhaps even the editor is able to tell you that it doesn't make sense. Such a check is very simple, but flow-control like checking all possible conditions and `if` and loops is very hard, so the compiler doesn't know that the expression won't ever be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Code after the `throw` should never be executed if it is invoked, the only exception being if there is an appropriate `catch`, which would then be executed. Same goes for C#. You shouldn't `throw` directly within the `try/catch` block anyways.

Comment: “*You shouldn’t `throw` directly within the `try/catch` block anyways*” - why not? That is the only way to throw custom exceptions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Explicitly throwing inside the try-catch block is a sign of bad architecture. Calling code that throws is fine and the correct use.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing are outputted because the throw statement will search for the matching catch exception, without execute statements following the throw statement
I think you have to change the catch to : `(char const* s)` or `(const char [])`  or something like this...
I don't remember but I can search it for you this evening if you want...
I already check the same catch exception

Comment: `catch (const char*)` and `catch (char const*)` are identical. And you can’t actually throw an array, so you can’t catch one.  `catch (const char[])` is likely to be treated the same as `catch (const char*)` the same as is done in function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me if anything after the throw statement is executed or not.

Explicit statements: No.

**BUT**: The destructor of all automatic objects will be correctly invoked as the stack is unwound.

> For example , in the code below , why do my IDE raises error for '10//0' if it is not going to be executed ?

The IDE is simply warning you about an obvious bug. It has not done any control flow analysis it just sees a bug as it generates the code.